# PowerShell не отображает часть текста BrowserSync

Tags: вёрстка, powershell, browsersync, frontend

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После обновления windows 10 в какой то момент, пропали подсказки BrowserSync из PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

Это не проблема галпа, просто в последних версиях Windows 10, изменили цветовую схему у powershell'a. Синий цвет фона powershell и такой же цвет у дополнительных параметров node.js. они сливаются.
Решение: Или меняем основной терминал т.е. powershell на командную строку в параметрах системы. Или оставляем powershell, но проделываем определенные действия:

1. Запустить powershell от имени администратора. Даем разрешение на
   запуск скриптов и подтверждаем командой:

   Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

   .

   2. Создаем свой профиль для powershell, командой: `New-Item -type file $PROFILE`
   3. В документах, заходим в папку PowerShell и открываем для редактирования файл **Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1**. в
      контекстном меню выбираем "изменить".
   4. Вставляем и сохраняем следующий код:

   (Get-Host).UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor="Gray";
   (Get-Host).UI.RawUI.backgroundColor="Black";
   (Get-Host).UI.RawUI.CursorSize=10;
   (Get-Host).UI.RawUI.WindowTitle="WorldCount Console";
   cls

   5. Перезапускаем powershell. Вот таким образом можно поменять визуальную конфигурацию powershell'a.

P.S. С цветами можно поиграться, доступные цвета: Black, DarkBlue, DarkGreen, DarkCyan, DarkRed, DarkMagenta, DarkYellow, Gray, DarkGray, Blue, Green, Cyan, Red, Magenta, Yellow, White.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Дополню, по умолчанию файла "_profile.ps1" нету, его можно создать с помощью команды: new-item -path $profile -itemtype file -force